# Simplification of rational expressions

Tags: fractions

I have the following expression:

$${2\over x-2} + {2 \over{x^2} -5x +6}$$

So I can simplify this as:

$${2 \over x -2} + {2 \over (x -3) (x-2)}$$

I make the common denominator to be ${(x-3)(x-2)}$

So I then apply ${(x-3)}$ to the left hand side which gives me:

$${2(x-3) + 2 \over (x-3)(x-2)}$$

I have clearly taken a wrong step because the answer in the book to the original expression is ${2 \over x-3}$ so I'm not sure how that answer was arrived at.

Comment: Your answer is good, just simplify a little further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did nothing wrong. Note that the numerator can be written as
$$2(x-3)+2=2x-6+2=2x-4=2(x-2).$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice, the following steps  $$\frac{2}{x-2}+\frac{2}{x^2-5x+6}$$ $$=2\left(\frac{1}{x-2}+\frac{1}{(x-2)(x-3)}\right)$$ $$=\frac{2}{x-2}\left(1+\frac{1}{x-3}\right)$$ $$=\frac{2}{x-2}\left(\frac{x-3+1}{x-3}\right)$$ $$=\frac{2}{x-2}\left(\frac{x-2}{x-3}\right)$$ $$=\frac{2}{x-3}$$
Your book has the correct expression.